# LM393 Window Comparator driving LED using 2N2222

Tags: led-driver, comparator

I have a circuit im trying to design utilizing the LM393 as a window comparator. I have them in wired or (outputs tied together) but im strugging in figuring out where I need resistors.

Looking at the application specs/data sheets, the recommended draw down current is 1mA, so using  12V power source that would be a 12k pull-up wired to the outputs of the comparator.

Where im struggling, is the NPN side of it. If i want the transistor in saturation (Hfe of 10), a collector current for the LED of 20mA, means i want a Base current of 2mA. the issue there is the loop of 12V-Ib(12K)-Rb(Ib)=0.7 isnt possible to solve, if Ib is .002.

From what i understand I want the 2n2222 device in saturation, which means roughly 0.7V at the base, 0.3 at the collector. Am i doing something wrong in my setup or calculations? In SIM it seems like its working for the most part, but my calculations dont add up so I want to be sure im doing it properly.  As a side note, the LED driven here is on the board, but it also needs to drive a chassis mount LED, my thought there was for an LED driver board where the Enabled output signal, is going to a PNP resistor, that should work correctly? Or is there a better way to do it

[image]

**Edit following an answer**: Tried it again using some different numbers from suggestion below. Vce of 1V, hfe=200, Ic of .02A still so

Vce= 1 = 12 - (.02)Rc - 2 - 1.0 == Rc = (12-2-1) / .02 = Rc = 450

Ib = .02/hfe = .02/200 = .0001
Rb Calc: 12 - (12k)(1u) - (1u)(Rb) - 0.7 = 0
Rb = 12-1.2-0.7/1u = Rb = 101k

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where is wired VP_COM ? To ground ? How is +12V ... 500.2 uV ?

Comment: IC supplies seem to be open: notice `+12` is not `+12v`, and `VP_COM` is not `0`.

Comment: Your VP_COM is not yet wired to GND ...

Answer (score 2):

> *If I want the transistor in saturation (Hfe of 10), a collector
> current for the LED of 20mA, means i want a Base current of 2mA.*

The collector current will be 25 mA when the supply is 12 volts and the resistor is 485 Ω but, if you look at the data sheet for the [2N2222](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/p2n2222a-d.pdf) you'll see that the typical gain will be about 200 at this collector current (with the transistor saturated to about 1 volt).

Also note it is about same gain when the collector current is 150 mA: -

[image]

Then if you look at the numbers in the table on page 2 you'll see that for a saturation of 1 volt at a collector current of 150 mA, the minimum gain will be 50. So, minimum gain is also going to be around 50 at a collector current of 25 mA.

[image]

You should also ask yourself if you need a BJT saturation voltage as low as 0.3 volts or, might 1 volt acceptable. If you really need less than 0.3 volts then use an N-channel MOSFET instead of a bipolar transistor.

Alternatively, don't use R85; let R48 dump all the current into the base (circa 2 mA).

> *Looking at the application specs/data sheets, the recommended draw
> down current is 1mA, so using 12V power source that would be a 12k
> pull-up wired to the outputs of the comparator.*

If you look in the [LM293 data sheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm393.pdf?ts=1711852954658&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLM393) you'll see that anywhere around 3 mA is probably better suited to your application: -

[image]

Comment: what makes 3mA better for the lm393? Also i tried the sim again with your numbers, using 20mA collector current, hfe of 200 means Base current is 100uA. That mean the Rb would be ~101k, and then Rc of 450 but pspice is only putting out around 13mA at the collector, editing my original post to show these calcs/sim

Comment: @user3182474 You don't decide on what base current to feed to the base like that because you'll never ever get what you want. What you want is to activate the BJT like a switch so that when activated, it carries the 20 mA and drops less than 1 volt across it. This means that the worst case hFE is going to be about 50. But, that still doesn't get below 1 volt when carrying 20 mA and you may need to assume hFE is as low as 20. Then you calculate the required base resistor.

Comment: 3 mA means you have all that current to deliver into the base and, that implies that you will get a low saturation voltage when the BJT is activated. hFE of 200 is typical only. If you use 3 mA, all that flows into the base and guarantees a low saturation voltage.

Comment: So, short out R85 and reduce R48 to 3k9. This will make a decent improvement.